# Metamask does not react on delivering gasPrice

Tags: web3js, metamask, cpp-ethereum

I am using following code to generate a new transaction using web3.js & metamask:

```
var web3dictdata = {
  gasPrice: web3.toHex(10),
  gasLimit: web3.toHex(210000),
  to: "0x92EB887e5de9f2C73C08483831F47dc0CD8f7B0c",
  value: web3.toWei(0.01, "ether"),
}

web3dictdata.data = "0x7770334469734b58777148446a4d4f5177345f4370634b59777154436e634f52777148436e4d4b56777076446b4d4b657770374372384b66777072446b634b657771544371734b5877345f436f734f4a77706e436d634f5477707a446a384f4e";

web3.eth.sendTransaction(web3dictdata, function(error, receipt) {
  if (error)
  {
      console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(receipt)
  }
});
```

But whenever I am launching it, it ends up in generating a new transaction filled with the data, 'to' address along with the value of a transaction.
The missing points are:

- gasPrice
- gasLimit

User, in order to successfully send a transaction, has to fill the gas Price on his own, which totally destroys my vision of the application

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The parameter is `gas` instead of `gasLimit`. I've ran into this issue several times.
2. It looks like `gasPrice` is getting through correctly. It shows 0,00000001 gwei, which is 10 wei, because that's what you're passing in. You have to convert gwei to wei to get the correct value using `web3.utils.toWei("10", "gwei").